# Dijkstra Shortest Path -Ghost AI Pacman-

Tags: java, algorithm, dijkstra, pacman

I've a question regarding my Dijkstra shortest-path algoritm I've made for my school project Pacman.

The algorithm works up-to a point where the 'smart' ghost can go multiple ways to Pacman. (Althought this is not everytime)

This happens (video):
https://vps.johnlokerse.nl/images/dijkstra_ghost_problem.mp4

The playfield is made out of the class 'Vakje' (cells). When the AI is doing the weird movements, as shown in the video, the debugging tool shows that he whats to go the shortest way, but at that point it wants to go back instead. I have no clue what the problem could be at this point. Any thoughts?

This is the code:

```
public class Slim extends Spookje {
private HashSet<Vakje> afgehandeldeNodes = new HashSet<Vakje>();
private Stack<Vakje> nietAfgehandeldeNodes = new Stack<>();
private Map<Vakje, Vakje> gelinkteAfgehandeldeNodes = new HashMap<>();
private Map<Vakje, Integer> lengteRoute = new HashMap<>();

public Slim(Vakje startLok, GameEventListener spel, GameEventListener veld) {
    super(startLok, spel, veld);
    this.img = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/img/slim.png")).getImage();
}

@Override
public void bewegen(Richting richting){
    verplaatsNaarVakje(zoekBuurvakjeOpKortstePad());
    afgehandeldeNodes.clear();
    nietAfgehandeldeNodes.clear();
    gelinkteAfgehandeldeNodes.clear();
    lengteRoute.clear();
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
    bewegen(Richting.NOORD);
}

public Vakje zoekBuurvakjeOpKortstePad() {
    lengteRoute.put(ligplaats, 0);
    nietAfgehandeldeNodes.add(ligplaats);
    while (nietAfgehandeldeNodes.size() > 0) {
        Vakje node = nietAfgehandeldeNodes.pop();
        afgehandeldeNodes.add(node);
        getAfTeHandelenBuren(node);
        if (node.getSpelObject() instanceof Pacman) {
            return getGevondenPad(node);
        }
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("Pacman is niet te vinden!");
}

private void getAfTeHandelenBuren(Vakje node) {
    java.util.List<Vakje> buren = getNietAfgehandeldeBuren(node);
    for (Vakje buur : buren) {
        lengteRoute.put(buur, lengteRoute.get(node) + 1);
        gelinkteAfgehandeldeNodes.put(buur, node);
        Spelobject object = buur.getSpelObject();
        if (!(object instanceof Muur)) {
            nietAfgehandeldeNodes.add(buur);
        }
        if (object instanceof Pacman) {
            break;
        }
    }
}

private java.util.List<Vakje> getNietAfgehandeldeBuren(Vakje node) {
    java.util.List<Vakje> buren = node.getBuren();
    Iterator<Vakje> iter = buren.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Vakje buur = iter.next();
        if (isAfgehandeld(buur)) {
            iter.remove();
        }
    }
    return buren;
}

private boolean isAfgehandeld(Vakje vertex) {
    return afgehandeldeNodes.contains(vertex);
}

public Vakje getGevondenPad(Vakje doel) {
    LinkedList<Vakje> route = new LinkedList<>();
    Vakje node = doel;
    if (gelinkteAfgehandeldeNodes.get(node) == null) {
        return null;
    }
    route.add(node);
    while (gelinkteAfgehandeldeNodes.get(node) != null) {
        node = gelinkteAfgehandeldeNodes.get(node);
        route.add(node);
    }

    Collections.reverse(route);
    return route.get(1);
}
```

Comment: This is next to impossible for us to debug, because the problem is not reproducable with this code. What you should do is isolate the problem. Test the algorithm on itself, without the context of the game. If that shows that your algorithm is wrong, you can come back here and post it as a self-contained, runnable problem.

Comment: This is why you should always program in english XD (I'm dutch anyway, but not smart enough to answer your question)

Comment: The problem is fixed. Had to use a Queue instead of a Stack. (nietAfgehandeldeNodes)

Comment: _afgehandeldeNodes_ sounds to me like _asdsdfjhlsdf_. It's difficult to understand what's going on here.